# Immutable.js: Data structure to represent 2D game field

Tags: javascript, immutability, immutable.js

I'm wondering What data structure should I use to represent a square game board(consider each cell can have some color). The most natural idea is a two dimensional List, but it's hard to query and change it.

So, now use a Map where keys are `${x}.${y}`(there is no tuples in JS:() and values are stings which represent colors
Something like this:

```
Map([['0.0', 'red'], ['0.1', 'red'], ['1.0', 'blue'], ['1.1', 'red']])
```

Is it ok to use such data structure? Is there any better solution in terms of Immutable.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am building some 2D game board of my own too, and I have came across the same problem. The solution I've made is [`Record`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record).

It simply looks like an object, also behave like one too. But with vanilla object, you cannot do the following mapping dictionary thing.

```
const dict = {};

const key1 = { row: 0, col: 1 };
const value1 = { some: 'value' };

dict[key1] = value; // will not work
```

This is what I want though, I tried to make the mapping as simple to deal with as possible. With `Record` and `Map` from **Immutable.js**, you can do the following.

```
import { Map, Record } from 'immutable';

const dict = Map();
const Pos = Record({ row: 0, col: 0 }); // some initial value.
const Val = Record({ some: 'value' }); // same here.

const key1 = new Pos({ row: 0, col: 1 });
const value1 = new Val({ some: 'value' });

dict = dict.set(key1, value1); // works like you wish
```

You can read the official doc for more information. Maybe you have a better solution, please let me know :).

Comment: Nice answer! Can I compare two Records?

Comment: sure you can, checkout Immutable.is()

Comment: I guess it make sense to add this to the answer

Comment: Nice. But maybe an `OrderedMap` to guarantee the order of the item? Or how do you print the matrix? I would be using two for loops so I need guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you cannot use a 2 dimensional array like so:

```
let square = [
    ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    ['orange', 'red', 'blue'],
    ['red', 'blue', 'blue']
];
```

Then you can add the above data structure to your map.

So to access the middle tile you can just use `[1][1]` index of the array.

Comment: >Is there any better solution in terms of Immutable.js?

Comment: the reasons you can find here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html

Comment: I am sure there is. You just asked for the data structure. That is how I would do it. The problem is if this is a "game board" as you say, why would you want it to be immutable? won't it change state at some point or another?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you think a List of Lists is hard to query and change. You can use arrays of length 2 as an `[x, y]` pair, and pass this to the `getIn`, `setIn`, and `updateIn` methods.

```
let grid = Immutable.toJS([
    ['red', 'green'],
    ['blue', 'yellow']
]);

grid.getIn([0, 1]); // => 'green';
grid = grid.setIn([0, 1], 'purple');
grid.getIn([0, 1]); // => 'purple';
grid = grid.updateIn([0, 0], cell => cell.toUpperCase());
grid.getIn([0, 0]); // => 'RED';
```

It's easy to apply some function to every cell in the grid with `map(...)`:

```
grid.map((row, x) => row.map(cell, y) => x + cell + y);
grid.get([1, 1]); // => '1yellow1'
```

One thing that might be trickier than with a Map is trying to find the coordinates of a value.

```
const x = grid.findIndex(row => row.contains('blue')); // => 1
const y = grid.get(x).indexOf('blue'); // => 0
grid.get([x, y]); // => blue
```